# help with microphone connection in TRRS audio jack

Tags: audio

I have the following TRRS audio female socket meant for audio/stereo headset. As i understand the tip(2) is for left channel, the ring(3) is for right channel, the sleeve(1) is for ground.
Now which connection 10 or 11 is used for microphone?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jack you have shown is a TRS jack, not TRRS.

Terminals 10 and 11 are switch contacts.  With no plug inserted, terminal 3 is connected to terminal 11, and 2 is connected to 10.  When the plug is inserted, these connections are broken.

If this was used as a headphone jack, the amplifier outputs would be connected to 2 and 3, with internal speakers connected to 10 and 11 - when a plug is inserted, the internal speakers would be disconnected.

Comment: all of the audio connectors looks same, is there a way to know which is TRS and TRRS from outside?

Comment: is this SparkFun TRRS 3.5mm Jack Breakout implement microphone? https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11570 if so which one is the microphone connection?

Comment: Yes, that Sparkfun jack is TRRS.  I haven't looked at headphone/microphone connections, but I would assume that the "Ring 2" connection would be the microphone (but I think I've heard that these connections are not entirely standardised).